# CSS not showing up on blackberry webworks

Tags: javascript, html, css, blackberry, blackberry-webworks

I'm testing out blackberry webworks, and I did all the steps mentioned on the blackberry website. But on my simulator, no css shows up. I have all the nessecary things installed, since the overall app works. There's just no css. Thanks in advance to anyone that can help.

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>jstest</title>
<style type="text/css">
#text{
    border-width: 0px;
    width: 100px;
}

#button{
background-color: #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius:6px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: poiner;
    border:none;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form"id="form">
<input type="button" id="button" value="click" onclick="thing()" />
<input type="text" id="text" />
</form>
<script>
    var button = document.getElementById("button");
    var div = document.getElementById("box");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    var form = document.getElementById("form");
    var array=[ "thanks for clicking", "keep on clicking", "click one more time", "why do you keep on clicking me?", "stop clicking me!","one more time... I dare you", "Stop it it hurts"];
function thing(){
    var y = array[Math.floor((Math.random() * array.length))];
    text.value=y;
}

function what(){
    text.value = "what";    
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Probably not *the* issue, but you have a missing space in `<form name="form"id="form">`

Comment: What simulator model & OS version are you testing on?